# MacBook Pro 2015 randomly restarting because of a problem

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 with 16GB RAM, 256GB SSD, and an Intel i7 Core. I am running macOS Big Sur 11.2.2. However, it will randomly restart and say that a problem occurred. On reporting the error, I get this:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8010fee1e6): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8010f78983, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff884d7c8e76, CR3: 0x00000002c64bc110, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0xffffff7f80000000, RBX: 0xffffff884d7c8e00, RCX: 0x000000002335f238, RDX: 0xffffff884d7c8e00
RSP: 0xffffffb0c35dba60, RBP: 0xffffffb0c35dba80, RSI: 0xffffff80196efcf8, RDI: 0xffffff803031c500
R8:  0x000000000230a0b4, R9:  0x0000000000000014, R10: 0xffffff8017bf5bc8, R11: 0xffffff8017bf5b20
R12: 0xffffff803031c500, R13: 0xffffff87c0000000, R14: 0xffffff803031c500, R15: 0xffffff8024231d98
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff8010f78983, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff884d7c8e76, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 1, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb0c35db480 : 0xffffff8010ebab4d 
0xffffffb0c35db4d0 : 0xffffff8010ffd7e3 
0xffffffb0c35db510 : 0xffffff8010fede1a 
0xffffffb0c35db560 : 0xffffff8010e5fa2f 
0xffffffb0c35db580 : 0xffffff8010eba3ed 
0xffffffb0c35db6a0 : 0xffffff8010eba6d8 
0xffffffb0c35db710 : 0xffffff80116bef9a 
0xffffffb0c35db780 : 0xffffff8010fee1e6 
0xffffffb0c35db900 : 0xffffff8010fedecd 
0xffffffb0c35db950 : 0xffffff8010e5fa2f 
0xffffffb0c35db970 : 0xffffff8010f78983 
0xffffffb0c35dba80 : 0xffffff8010f8ec3a 
0xffffffb0c35dbac0 : 0xffffff8010f705c8 
0xffffffb0c35dbb30 : 0xffffff8010f6f0ee 
0xffffffb0c35dbb60 : 0xffffff8010f70475 
0xffffffb0c35dbb90 : 0xffffff8010f6f612 
0xffffffb0c35dbbd0 : 0xffffff8010f5ac0f 
0xffffffb0c35dbd20 : 0xffffff8010f5a233 
0xffffffb0c35dbd50 : 0xffffff8010eeda8a 
0xffffffb0c35dbd90 : 0xffffff801143cb88 
0xffffffb0c35dbe00 : 0xffffff8011459c27 
0xffffffb0c35dbe80 : 0xffffff801145a063 
0xffffffb0c35dbed0 : 0xffffff8010eb2280 
0xffffffb0c35dbf00 : 0xffffff8010e5f9fb 

Process name corresponding to current thread: dart

Mac OS version:
20D80

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000010c00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8010e00000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000010c10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8010e10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8010d00000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3263539797515
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000002f7da216210
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000379d5af09 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 2674920345481: >usb.!UUserHCI  1 (addr 0xffffff7fb179e000, size 102400)
last stopped kext at 2823517914954: >usb.!UUserHCI  1 (addr 0xffffff7fb179e000, size 102400)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.18
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>AGPM   119
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IBDWGraphics    16.0.1
>!AHDA  283.15
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.3d9
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.3d9
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ASMCLMU   212
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!ALPC  3.1
>!UCardReader   511.60.2
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.81.1
>!AAHCIPort 346
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4030.5
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  585
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.3d9
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    930.1
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOGraphics!F   585
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AActuatorDriver   4400.28
|IOAHCI!F   294
>!AHIDKeyboard  223
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4030.5
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.3d9
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   61
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AHSSPISupport 61
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.3d9
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.60.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

I don't know what's happening here. Does anybody have any insights that could help?

Another log from earlier today:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80171ee1e6): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801714558c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x0000000203e62001, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffffffffffffff, RCX: 0xffffff7f80000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000001
RSP: 0xffffffb0c8313810, RBP: 0xffffffb0c8313a00, RSI: 0xffffffb0c8313920, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x0000000000000023, R9:  0x0000000000000001, R10: 0xffffff7f80000000, R11: 0xffffff801d400000
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffffb0c8313920, R14: 0xfffffffff0000000, R15: 0xffffff8035046200
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff801714558c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000008, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb0c8313230 : 0xffffff80170bab4d 
0xffffffb0c8313280 : 0xffffff80171fd7e3 
0xffffffb0c83132c0 : 0xffffff80171ede1a 
0xffffffb0c8313310 : 0xffffff801705fa2f 
0xffffffb0c8313330 : 0xffffff80170ba3ed 
0xffffffb0c8313450 : 0xffffff80170ba6d8 
0xffffffb0c83134c0 : 0xffffff80178bef9a 
0xffffffb0c8313530 : 0xffffff80171ee1e6 
0xffffffb0c83136b0 : 0xffffff80171edecd 
0xffffffb0c8313700 : 0xffffff801705fa2f 
0xffffffb0c8313720 : 0xffffff801714558c 
0xffffffb0c8313a00 : 0xffffff8017144277 
0xffffffb0c8313a60 : 0xffffff801768c576 
0xffffffb0c8313a90 : 0xffffff801733f624 
0xffffffb0c8313b10 : 0xffffff801733ed70 
0xffffffb0c8313b50 : 0xffffff8017344aa5 
0xffffffb0c8313bd0 : 0xffffff8017350e34 
0xffffffb0c8313c90 : 0xffffff8017345e4a 
0xffffffb0c8313cc0 : 0xffffff801733df1f 
0xffffffb0c8313d20 : 0xffffff8017345a7a 
0xffffffb0c8313d40 : 0xffffff80176544ce 
0xffffffb0c8313e00 : 0xffffff80176702b9 
0xffffffb0c8313f40 : 0xffffff80177698cb 
0xffffffb0c8313fa0 : 0xffffff80170601f6 

Process name corresponding to current thread: launchd

Mac OS version:
20D80

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000016e00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8017000000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000016e10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8017010000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8016f00000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
System shutdown begun: YES
Panic diags file available: NO (0xe00002cd)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4155339305489
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000003c77d85f5f5
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x000000037eb0abd4 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 2295532673824: @filesystems.msdosfs    1.10 (addr 0xffffff7fb81dd000, size 57344)
last stopped kext at 3696055486110: >usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2 (addr 0xffffff8019e48000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.18
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>AGPM   119
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
>pmtelemetry    1
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.3d9
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!A!IBDWGraphics    16.0.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.3d9
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!ALPC  3.1
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!UCardReader   511.60.2
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.81.1
>!AAHCIPort 346
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4030.5
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    930.1
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.3d9
|IONDRVSupport  585
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
|IOGraphics!F   585
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AActuatorDriver   4400.28
|IOAHCI!F   294
>!AHIDKeyboard  223
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4030.5
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.3d9
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   61
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AHSSPISupport 61
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.3d9
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.60.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

I don't know how to read a log like this, so if anybody does, I'd love to hear some insight and hopefully a solution. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

It's happened a couple more times. Here is a log:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800cbee1e6): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800cb78983, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff85a7504276, CR3: 0x000000003312825e, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0xffffff7f80000000, RBX: 0xffffff85a7504200, RCX: 0x00000000189d4108, RDX: 0xffffff85a7504200
RSP: 0xffffff8020b03b70, RBP: 0xffffff8020b03b90, RSI: 0xffffff80189d4098, RDI: 0xffffff8030b86f00
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0xffffff8690a619a0, R10: 0xffffff86bdccf501, R11: 0x0000000000000050
R12: 0xffffff8030b86f00, R13: 0xffffff87c0000000, R14: 0xffffff8030b86f00, R15: 0xffffff80189d4108
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff800cb78983, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffff85a7504276, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 1, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8020b03590 : 0xffffff800cabab4d 
0xffffff8020b035e0 : 0xffffff800cbfd7e3 
0xffffff8020b03620 : 0xffffff800cbede1a 
0xffffff8020b03670 : 0xffffff800ca5fa2f 
0xffffff8020b03690 : 0xffffff800caba3ed 
0xffffff8020b037b0 : 0xffffff800caba6d8 
0xffffff8020b03820 : 0xffffff800d2bef9a 
0xffffff8020b03890 : 0xffffff800cbee1e6 
0xffffff8020b03a10 : 0xffffff800cbedecd 
0xffffff8020b03a60 : 0xffffff800ca5fa2f 
0xffffff8020b03a80 : 0xffffff800cb78983 
0xffffff8020b03b90 : 0xffffff800cb8ec3a 
0xffffff8020b03bd0 : 0xffffff800cb705c8 
0xffffff8020b03c40 : 0xffffff800cb6f0ee 
0xffffff8020b03c70 : 0xffffff800cb70475 
0xffffff8020b03ca0 : 0xffffff800cb6f612 
0xffffff8020b03ce0 : 0xffffff800cb5ac0f 
0xffffff8020b03e30 : 0xffffff800cb5a233 
0xffffff8020b03e60 : 0xffffff800caeda8a 
0xffffff8020b03ea0 : 0xffffff800d03cb88 
0xffffff8020b03f10 : 0xffffff800d03c983 
0xffffff8020b03f30 : 0xffffff800d03c959 
0xffffff8020b03f40 : 0xffffff800d1698cb 
0xffffff8020b03fa0 : 0xffffff800ca601f6 

Process name corresponding to current thread: System Information

Mac OS version:
20D80

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000c800000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff800ca00000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000c810000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff800ca10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800c900000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5803029278122
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000005471f7fb1b8
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000386c4b709 0x0000000000000000
last started kext at 23817787940: >!AUpstreamUserClient 3.6.8 (addr 0xffffff7facf79000, size 12288)
last stopped kext at 220578992945: >!A!ILpssI2C 3.0.60 (addr 0xffffff800df33000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.18
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>AGPM   119
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
>!ABacklight    180.3
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
>eficheck   1
>pmtelemetry    1
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.3d9
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!ALPC  3.1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IBDWGraphics    16.0.1
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    8.0.3d9
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!UCardReader   511.60.2
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.81.1
>!AAHCIPort 346
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4030.5
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    930.1
|IONDRVSupport  585
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IOGraphics!F   585
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.3d9
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AActuatorDriver   4400.28
|IOAHCI!F   294
>!AHIDKeyboard  223
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4030.5
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.3d9
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   61
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AHSSPISupport 61
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.3d9
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.60.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

I still don't know what's going on.

Comment: The thirst thing you can do is update the Mac Os x system to last version 11.4. Else, this restarts comes only when you use VirtualBox?

Comment: @Jean_JD I don't have VirtualBox installed on my machine... why?

Comment: VirtualBox is present : `loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.18`

Comment: I installed it once months ago to try it out and uninstalled it days after. Could it still be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I don't know. You can scan your system with Etrechek. It give most informations.

Comment: @PeterNielsen You did not fully uninstall VirtualBox, otherwise its KEXTs would not be appearing in your panic report. Did you run the uninstaller, or did you just drag the app to the trash? As Jean_JD correctly intuits, you should definitely try running without third party KEXTs and see if this still reproduces.

Comment: @pion How do you make it run without the third party kexts?

Comment: @PeterNielsen Did you run the actual uninstaller? That will do it (for VirtualBox). You can also temporarily run without extensions by booting in Safe Mode (Shift during boot) but that isn't practical for long-term debugging.

Comment: I don't have an actual installer because I trashed Vbox